Independent and interdependent notebooks
My Mathematica 11.2 home edition license under Windows 10 allows only for two independent notebooks/processes at a time. Is this what the Mathematica license calls "2 Frontends"? Does this mean the number of parallel and independent Mathematica runtime environments possible? In the Mathematica online documentation I find absolutely nothing about that.
I can open more notebooks, arbitrarily many, but then they are interdependent. For example, if I set x=3 in one notebook, then in the dependent other one x also has the value 3 assigned. And if here I set x=4, then in the first one I see the value 4, instead of what I had assigned in that notebook. But these are not the only undesirable interactions. For example, the input/output counter is common to all interdependent notebooks.
For me it makes no sense at all to work with such interdependent notebooks. With only two independent notebooks in Mathematica, I can hardly develop programs at all. For instance, if I compare various versions of a program, I need all these versions with their own independent name space and runtime environment. From the CAS Maxima, for example, I am used to be able to open up as many completely independent processes as I want on my computer, and I often need half a dozen of them or more.
I see that all Mathematica single place licenses, even today with version 14, offer only these two independent processes, these "2 frontends".
Am I overlooking anything, or am I really stuck with only two Mathematica processes in parallel?
Thanks for any help!

Related: Is there a way to separate variables between multiple notebooks?.

To be honest, this artificial limitation to me doesn't make any sense at all, also I don't really find it very consumer friendly. However, dura lex, sed lex.

@Domen, thank you very much for the link! The answers given there basically solve my problem. I don't understand, why an issue so fundamental for the user is not addressed in the Mathematica documentation, at some place where it can be found.
